# Ways to improve battery life on Droid Incredible?

Tags: battery-life, performance, htc-droid-incredible

Out of the box, I noticed my Incredible has *a lot* of stuff running/turned on by default.  Besides the basics of turning off WiFi, GPS, and BlueTooth when I'm not using them, are there more steps I can take to make my battery last longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I believe reducing use of vibration helps save battery life on a phone. So for the Incredible, I even disabled the feature of vibrating when entering keystrokes.

Here are some good tips from [wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Your-Cell-Phone-Battery-Last-Longer).

Comment: FYI, for HTC, keyboard "haptic feedback" is found in the sound/display settings.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to 2G when there's no need to use 3G networks is also increasing the battery life.

Comment: How do you switch?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing I've seen is to dim the backlight as much as possible (while remaining comfortable for your eyes), as well as lowering screen time-out length. Another big killer is to stay connected to wifi or 3g with a very weak signal. If it is at the point of losing connection and reconnecting repeatedly, it will eat through the battery very quickly.